# What algorithm to use for Java object encryption?

Tags: encryption, java

I am developing a Java application and I need to do a symmetric encryption to secure some of my sensitive information. There are many algorithms like AES, DES 3DES in Java cryptography. What is the best algorithm should I use to encrypt my sensitive information?

Mostly I do have string values and there are couple of instances that I need to secure Java object.

Comment: AES is the currently used algorithm, but you really need to know what you want to protect from. Maybe you'd need a MAC too, or would be better of using Asymmetric encryption. RE GeorgeBailey's comment, I believe that the current standard order of operation used is GCM, but that's for AEAD.

Comment: What's the context?  In memory, on disk, over the network?

Answer (score 2):

**AES-128 (or higher)** is the recommended algorithm.

You should also choose a good **Chaining Method** with a random **Initialization Vector**. Padding variable length source data is helpful since AES is a block algorithm. `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding` is a good option.

The encryption **Key** should be generated from a **Cryptographically Secure (Pseudo-)Random Number Generator**. (i.e. Java's `SecureRandom`)

Alternatively, the encryption key could be Derived from a reasonably strong Password using a suitable Key Derivation Function. ([comparison here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/138363/why-is-md5-considered-a-vulnerable-algorithm/138369#138369))

I'm assuming you need to encrypt data at rest. Key Management will have to be considered.

If you need to encrypt data in transit you'd also need MITM and Integrity verification, which is best accomplished with TLS. (HTTPS)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to secure a Java object you need to use [SealedObject](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/SealedObject.html) class.

Following is a sample code.

Using AES-128 bit and writing into a file as a sealed object.

```
  try {
//Generate a key
  KeyGenerator    gen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
  gen.init(128);
  Key sKey = gen.generateKey();

  Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
  c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,sKey);

// do the sealing
  Car car=new Car("My car ",2014);
  SealedObject so = new SealedObject(car,c);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("Objects.obj");
  ObjectOutputStream oOut = new ObjectOutputStream(out);

//Save the key
  oOut.writeObject(sKey);

//Save the sealed object
  oOut.writeObject(so);
  oOut.close();
  System.out.println("SealedObject was written to Object file");

  } catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println(e);
  }
 }
```

Decryption goes as follows. It reads the sealed object and decrypt using the same key.

```
try {
  FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("Objects.obj");
  ObjectInputStream oIn = new ObjectInputStream(in);

//Read the key
  Key sKey= (Key) oIn.readObject();

//Read the sealed object
  SealedObject so= (SealedObject) oIn.readObject();
//unsealded the object
  Car car = (Car) so.getObject(sKey);
  car.getNo();
  car.getYear();

  } catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println(e);
  }
```

Securing the symmetric key is very important here but it is off topic.

AES(256) is the modern standard and its been used in US federal and other organisations. AES has 128,192 and 256 bit encryption. DES is considered as "Old" and it has many [vulnerabilities](http://paginas.fe.up.pt/~ei10109/ca/des-vulnerabilities.html). Successor of DES is 3DES. 3DES mitigates many vulnerabilities found in DES. But it is considered as slow when it comes to software implementations,  because it's applying the DES in 3 times.

So always use AES when you are in doubt.

Comment: Don't use DES! Isn't that insecure? Use AES instead.

Comment: Sorry I just use the DES as a code example.

Comment: Thanks guys. I used AES in the code instead of DES as you mentioned. It worked !

Comment: I think it would be nice if you changed the code example to use AES to make the answer clearer. The risk is that someone comes along and just copy paste the code, or don't read the full answer... But apart from that, really nice answer!

Comment: @Andres : Code updated as requested

Answer (score 0):

DES and 3DES aren't really considered strong encryption anymore.  Look at Rijndael AES, there is an implementation available for java ( just search stack overflow). Ensure you read up on how to use salts and how to securely store your key.